# Protected fields access from brother

Tags: php, inheritance

I reveal iteresting behavior of php >= 5.2

```
class A {
    protected $a = 'A';
    public function __get($f){ return 'field_'.$f; }
}

class B extends A {}
class C extends A {
    public function foo() {
        $b = new B();
        echo $b->a;
    }
}

$c = new C();
$c->foo();
```

I expect it print `field_a`, but it print `A`.
Also. If I remove magic from `A` - I expect fatal error, but it still print `A` in `php>=5.2`.

If we overwrite `B::$a` we get another behavior - `fatal error`.

Why?
Is it feature or bug?

Fiddles:
 - http://3v4l.org/tiOC5 - get foreign field
 - http://3v4l.org/uT9PC - get fatal error

Comment: Because `B` does not *define* `$a` you're actually accessing a property of `A`. I can understand why this is somewhat *counter-intuitive*.

Comment: @Yoshi, but how can I use it in `C`, when I don't know redefined or not redefined `$a` in `B`?

Comment: Personally I would suggest that you do not try to access parent properties through siblings. Matter of fact, you could simply do `this->a`.

Comment: I reveal it in my database models classes. My DBA create a `data` field and all brakes because `$m->data` __getter returns me protected array instead of field `data`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of PHP's very funky rules for who can and cannot access class properties.

Read about it here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

The key part is this:

> The visibility of a property or method can be defined by prefixing the
>   declaration with the keywords public, protected or private. Class
>   members declared public can be accessed everywhere. **Members declared
>   protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by
>   inherited and parent classes.** Members declared as private may only be
>   accessed by the class that defines the member.

Emphasis mine. You are allowed to access the protected variables of any object that inherits from the same class you inherit from, even on another object. This also includes accessing the private properties of other objects of the exact same class.

Whether this is a good idea or a weird feature is up for debate, but it seems to be intended.

Comment: Thanks for cite. Have you answer to: `Why my code in class C should rely on "is $a field overwritten in class B?"` question also? And how can I check it?

Comment: As soon as you override the field $a in class B, it becomes a class member of class B. Since class C does not extend from class B, C is not allowed to access the property anymore, which causes the error. (This is why many people consider it a very weird feature)

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you declare a variable it won't use the `__get` magic method.

So by declaring `protected $a = 'A';`, you are excluding `a` from the `__get` cycle. It will skip the magic method and go straight for the actual property.

Comment: Exactly. `protected` means full access to all subclasses, so the field is fully accessible for `B`, which means that the magic method will not be invoked. If the field were `private`, it would be a different story.

Comment: but if I overwrite this field in `B` class I get `Cannot access protected property B::$a`...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for the magic methods [__get()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and [__set()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) you'll see that they only run in the case of reading/writing to an inaccessible field.

In your example `$a` is accessible from `class C` as it's defined as a protected field (inheriting/parent classes can view protected fields/methods). If you change `$a` to a private field it should have to call the magic method for your example.

Comment: My question is `Why this field is accessible?`, not `how __get works`. Why my code in C class should rely on `is $a field overwritten in B class`?

Comment: This is what I answered if you read my full post...

'as it's defined as a protected field (`inheriting/parent classes can view protected fields/methods)`'

Comment: I know that, but I ask why. I can not accept the fact that this is normal behavior. It is a terrible behavior. Correct answer is `It is old known bug`